# Как правильно инкапсулировать функцию в Javascript

Tags: javascript, классы, методы

```js
class Point{
        constructor(x, y, cl, i){
            this.x = (x=='') ? Randing(hht_field) : x;
            this.y = (y=='') ? Randing(wth_field) : y;
            this.cl = cl;
            this.i = i;
        }

        //Рандомные координаты
       Randing(arg){
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (arg/sh));
       }
}
```

функция Randing не срабатывает, или проще оставить ее вне класса?

Comment: что за `sh` в функции и откуда он берется?

Comment: `this` нужен перед вызовом

Answer (score 1):

```
class Point{
        constructor(x, y, cl, i){
            this.x = (x=='') ? this.Randing(hht_field) : x;
            this.y = (y=='') ? this.Randing(wth_field) : y;
            this.cl = cl;
            this.i = i;
        }

        //Рандомные координаты
       Randing(arg){
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (arg/sh));
       }
}
```

Ответ пришел в голову спустя пару секунд после отправки вопроса, и как только я упустил такое)